# How do I plot something as simple as f(x) = x^2 ln x?

Tags: plotting

I’m having trouble with the natural log. When I plot it I keep getting different answers, any help is appreciated!

Comment: What happens when you enter `ln` in the help center search bar?  (Click on first link.  See also the first example under "Applications".)

Comment: http://www.wolfram.com/wolfram-u/catalog/gen005/

Comment: Log[x] is the equivalent of ln[x]. if you want a different base for log, use Log[b,x] which gives log of x in basis b

Answer (score 1):

First define a function in *Mathematica*,

```
f[x_] := x^2*Log[x]
```

As mentioned in the comments for $ln(x)$ the MMA built-in function is `Log[x]`

Now plot the above function `f[x]`,

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1.2}]
```

[image]